# My Algorithm only fails for large values - How do I debug this?

Tags: algorithm, debugging

I'm working on transcribing [as3delaunay](https://github.com/nodename/as3delaunay/) to [Objective-C](https://github.com/Wayfarer247/ASDelaunay). For the most part, the entire algorithm works and creates graphs exactly as they should be. However, for large values (thousands of points), the algorithm *mostly* works, but creates some incorrect graphs.

I've been going back through and checking the most obvious places for error, and I haven't been able to actually find anything. For smaller values I ran the output of the original algorithm and placed it into JSON files. I then read that output in to my own tests (tests with 3 or 4 points only), and debugged until the output matched; I checked the output of the two algorithms line for line, and found the discrepancies. But I can't feasibly do that for 1000 points.

Answers don't need to be specific to my situation (although suggesting tools I can use would be excellent).

**How can I debug algorithms that only fail for large values?**

Comment: Why can't you write a program to automate checking the output line-by-line?

Answer (score 4):

If you are transcribing an existing algorithm to Objective-C, do you have a working original in some other language? In that case, I would be inclined to put in print statements in both versions and debug the first discrepancy (the first, because later discrepancies could be knock-on errors).

I think it is very likely that the program also makes mistakes for smaller graphs, but more rarely. My first step would in fact be to use the working original (or some other means) to run a large number of automatically checked test runs on small graphs, hoping to find the bug on some more manageable input size.

Answer (score 2):

## Find the threshold

If it works for 3 or 4 items, but not for 1000, then there's probably some threshold in between.  Use a binary search to find that threshold.

The threshold itself may be a clue.  For example, maybe it corresponds to a magic value in the algorithm or to some other value you wouldn't expect to be correlated.  For example, perhaps it's a problem when the number of items exceeds the number of pixels in the x direction of the chart you're trying to draw.  The clue might be enough to help you solve the problem.  If not, it may give you a clue as to how to force the problem to happen with a smaller value (e.g., debug it with a very narrow chart area).

The threshold may be smaller than you think, and may be directly debuggable.

If the threshold is a big value, like 1000.  Perhaps you can set a conditional breakpoint to skip right to iteration 999, and then single-step from there.

There may not be a definite threshold, which suggests that it's not the magnitude of the input size, but some other property you should be looking at (e.g., powers of 10 don't work, but everything else does).

## Decompose the problem and write unit tests

This can be tedious but is often extremely valuable--not just for the current issue, but for the future.  Convince yourself that each individual piece works in isolation.

## Re-visit recent changes

If it used to work and now it doesn't, look at the most recent changes first.  Source control tools are very useful in helping you remember what has changed recently.

## Remove code and add it back piece by piece

Comment out as much code as you can and still get some kind of reasonable output (even if that output doesn't meet all the requirements).  For example, instead of using a complicated rounding function, just truncate values.  Comment out code that adds decorative touches.  Put assert(false) in any special case handlers you don't think should be activated for the test data.

Now verify that output, and slowly add back the functionality you removed, one baby step at a time.  Test thoroughly at each step.

## Profile the code

Profiling is usually for optimization, but it can sometimes give you insight into code, especially when the data size is too large for single-stepping through the debugger.  I like to use line or statement counts.  Is the loop body executing the number of times you expect?  Or twice as often?  Or not at all?  How about the then and else clauses of those if statements?  Logic bugs often become very obvious with this type of profiling.